# How do I animate a square around a block?

Tags: css, css-animations

My animation works but after one turn, the square rotate of 45 deg,
I don't understand why.
https://codepen.io/igamanstudio/pen/ZPYWWO

```css
.card {
  /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 150px auto;
}

.anim-square {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: spin 20s linear infinite;
}

.losange-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.losange-1 {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  background: red;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  animation: invert-spin 22.5s linear infinite;
}
.losange-1 .img {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.losange-1 .img:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  z-index: 999;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: url("https://loremflickr.com/60/60/girl/all") center center;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: center;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */
.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/* Add some padding inside the card container */
.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes invert-spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4> 
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
  </div>
  <div class="anim-square">
    <div class="losange-wrap">
      <div class="losange-1">
        <div class="img"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  background: red ;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  animation: invert-spin 22.5s linear infinite;
```

Comment: I recommend adding complete code in this post as a runnable snippet, rather than a linked codepen (which can change and be moved over time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to set the same duration for both animation then you need to use `rotate(-315deg)` for the image since you are setting `rotate(45deg)`. The difference should be `360deg` like the main container that will animate from `0deg` to `360deg`

```css
.card {
  /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 150px auto;
}

.anim-square {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  //background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
}

.losange-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.losange-1 {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  background: red;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  animation: invert-spin 5s linear infinite;
}

.losange-1 .img {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.losange-1 .img:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  z-index: 999;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: url('https://loremflickr.com/60/60/girl/all') center center;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: center;
}


/* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/* Add some padding inside the card container */

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes invert-spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-315deg);
    transform: rotate(-315deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
  </div>
  <div class="anim-square">
    <div class="losange-wrap">
      <div class="losange-1">
        <div class="img"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```